# Global variable gives local variable refrenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I am making a game in pygame in which you have the option to change character in the menu. my problematic code looks like this.

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
screen_w = 1200
screen_h = 700
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
light_grey = (135, 135, 135)
medium_grey = (100, 100, 100)
grey =  (90, 90, 90)
global currentsprite
currentsprite = 1
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
smalltext = pygame.font.Font("font1.ttf", 20)
normaltext = pygame.font.Font("font1.ttf", 40)
mediumtext = pygame.font.Font("font1.ttf", 30)
largetext = pygame.font.Font("font1.ttf", 60)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_w, screen_h))
importsprite1 = pygame.image.load("CharacterSprite1.png")
importsprite2 = pygame.image.load("CharacterSprite2.png")
importsprite3 = pygame.image.load("CharacterSprite3.png")
importsprite1fireball1 = pygame.image.load("RedFireBall1.png")
importsprite2fireball1 = pygame.image.load("PurpleFireBall1.png")
importsprite3fireball1 = pygame.image.load("YellowFireBall1.png")





def format_image(image, factor, grid_x, grid_y):
    step1 = image.get_size()
    new_image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(step1[0] * factor), int(step1[1] * factor)))
    window.blit(new_image, (grid_x, grid_y))


def Button(msg, font, x, y, w, h, c):
    pygame.draw.rect(window, c, (x, y, w, h))
    textsurf, textrect = text_labels(msg, font)
    textrect.center = ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)))
    window.blit(textsurf, textrect)


def ChooseCharacter():
    window.fill(light_grey)
    Button("Sprite 1", largetext, 100, 50, 250, 150, grey)
    Button("Sprite 2", largetext, 100, 280, 250, 150, grey)
    Button("Sprite 3", largetext, 100, 500, 250, 150, grey)
    if currentsprite == 1:
        format_image(importsprite1, 1.35, (screen_w/2+50), 65)
    elif currentsprite == 2:
        format_image(importsprite2, 1.35, (screen_w/2+50), 65)
    elif currentsprite == 3:
        format_image(importsprite3, 1.35, (screen_w/2+50), 65)
    pygame.display.update()
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("WHY")
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if onPos(100, 50, 250, 150):
                    currentsprite = 1
                    DrawMainMenu()
                if onPos(100, 200, 250, 150):
                    currentsprite = 2
                    DrawMainMenu()
                if onPos(100, 350, 250, 150):
                    currentsprite = 3
                    DrawMainMenu()
                if onPos(100, 500, 250, 150):
                    DrawMainMenu()


def text_labels(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
def onPos(x, y, w, h):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def DrawMainMenu():
    window.fill(light_grey)
    Button("Start", mediumtext, 100, 50, 250, 100, grey)
    Button("Multiplayer", mediumtext, 100, 200, 250, 100, grey)
    Button("Choose Character", mediumtext, 100, 350, 250, 100, grey)
    Button("Exit", mediumtext, 100, 500, 250, 100, grey)
    if currentsprite == 1:
        format_image(importsprite1, 1.35, (screen_w/2+50), 65)
    elif currentsprite == 2:
        format_image(importsprite2, 1.35, (screen_w/2+50), 65)
    elif currentsprite == 3:
        format_image(importsprite3, 1.35, (screen_w/2+50), 65)
    pygame.display.update()
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("WHY")
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if onPos(100, 50, 250, 100):
                    print("clicked start")
                if onPos(100, 200, 250, 100):
                    print("clicked Multiplayer")
                if onPos(100, 350, 250, 100):
                    ChooseCharacter()
                if onPos(100, 500, 250, 100):
                    exit()
DrawMainMenu()
```

the problem I am experiencing is it keeps stating that the local variable currentsprite is referenced before assignment, I have tried putting `global currentsprite` before I declare currentsprite but that does not work. If it helps
I am on windows 10 using IDLE 3.7.0.
TIA

EDIT:
I actually use the variable `currentsprite` in another function in which I do change it's value (and yes that works) I will reiterate changing the value of currentsprite works ONLY in another variable but even refrencing it in ChooseCharacter gives an error. full code can be seen here-pastebin.com/YjU8KiuV

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: sorry about that full code here-pastebin.com/YjU8KiuV

Comment: Post you MCVE here by editing your question. Make sure it is minimal.

Comment: @ImaGonnaDie that is not a [mcve]

Comment: I know I decided to show my full code if anything else arises.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, to read a global variable inside a function you do not need to declare it as `global` (inside the function). This is only required if you want to modify the value of the global object within the function. Also I see some inconsistent indentation (after declaring the function) - solve that first. Still, try to add `global currentsprite` in the function just in case you are modifying it somewhere else:

```
def ChooseCharacter():
    global currentsprite
    ...
```

Comment: sorry I should have stated this but I actually use the variable `currentsprite` in another function in which I do change it's value (and yes that works)

Comment: No, changing the value of currentsprite works **ONLY** in another variable but even refrencing it in ChooseCharacter gives an error full code can be seen here-https://pastebin.com/YjU8KiuV